# Android log deobfuscation/retrace

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, deobfuscation

I need some help with Android log file deobfuscation .

The problem is that if I have an exception like:

```
  ...
    10-16 10:03:10.488: E/AndroidRuntime(25723): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-16 10:03:10.488: E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at proguard.test.a.a(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

the retrace return original log but if I paste to log function name and line like:

```
  ...
    10-16 10:03:10.480: I/ghghghg(25723): Crash in function [proguard.test.a.a() Line : -1 ]
    ...
```

the retrace doesn't deofescates that log line.
I know that there is an **-regex** parameter to retrace command but I can't find any explanation or sample. The Proguard retrace manual is unavailable on http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html.

How can I configure the retrace to deobfuscate custom lines in log?

Answer (score 1):

The ProGuard manual ([online](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/usage.html), and also included in the ProGuard distribution) contains an example. It uses java.util.regex syntax with some additional wildcards for class names, etc.

Comment: Hi, can you please give me some example for regex and custom log file.I tried to use retrace with regex "(?:\\s*%c:.*)|(?:\\s*at\\s+%c.%m\\s*\\(.*?(?::%l)?\\)\\s*)" and it doesn't work even for standard android exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [recat](https://github.com/EverythingMe/recat). It's a python script based on logcat-color, made exactly for this scenario, on-the-fly logcat deobfuscation (doesn't work on Windows though).